# Convert dataframe to 1 and 0

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a big tibble like this:

```
a b c d e f
1 1 1 0 0 1
4 5 1 1 0 1
3 1 0 0 0 0
```

And convert it to this (ideally with the tidyverse) so 0s remain while 1 and bigger are converted to 1:

```
a b c d e f 
1 1 1 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 0 1
1 1 0 0 0 0
```

Variables have distinct names and go form second column to last column.

Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A tidyverse approach could be:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
   mutate_all(~ +(.x > 0))

  a b c d e f
1 1 1 1 0 0 1
2 1 1 1 1 0 1
3 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

If you want all but the first column transformed, you could do:

```
df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-1), ~ +(.x > 0))
```

Comment: I think you can do it without `mutate_all`, `+(df > 0)`

Comment: @RonakShah - Absolutely - this answer is in response to OP stating 'ideally with the tidyverse' .

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pmin` which will select minimum between the 1 and the value in the dataframe.

```
pmin(df, 1)

#  a b c d e f
#1 1 1 1 0 0 1
#2 1 1 1 1 0 1
#3 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(1L, 4L, 3L), b = c(1L, 5L, 1L), c = c(1L, 
1L, 0L), d = c(0L, 1L, 0L), e = c(0L, 0L, 0L), f = c(1L, 1L, 
0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something odd, but I get unintended results with this using for instance: `set.seed(1); df <- data.frame(matrix(sample(0:5,10,replace=TRUE),nrow=5))`

Comment: `df[] <- lapply(df, pmin, 1)` on the otherhand, does work as intended.

Comment: @thelatemail yeah, I get `NA`s too, that is strange. Converting to matrix works `pmin(as.matrix(df), 1)` but why doesn't `pmin(df, 1)` work directly? Especially when the `df` in the post is also dataframe.

Comment: It seems like a bit of a gotcha, but I suppose it makes sense given that functions like `mean(df)` don't work like that anymore. There looks to be some funky transformations when using `pmin` with anything that is not a vector. This seems potentially worth bug-discussion. At least a nicer warning message could be specified.